# Why does my ItemsControl have such slow performance?

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, xaml, itemscontrol

I have an ItemsControl that looks like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CombinedPieChartData}"
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Canvas>
                <Path Fill="{Binding Color}">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <GeometryGroup>
                            <PathGeometry>
                                <PathFigure StartPoint="{Binding FirstPoint1}">
                                    <PathFigure.Segments>
                                        <LineSegment Point="{Binding SecondPoint1}"/>
                                    </PathFigure.Segments>
                                </PathFigure>
                            </PathGeometry>
                        </GeometryGroup>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
                <Path Fill="{Binding Color}">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <GeometryGroup>
                            <PathGeometry>
                                <PathFigure StartPoint="{Binding Center}">
                                    <PathFigure.Segments>
                                        <LineSegment Point="{Binding FirstPoint}"/>
                                        <ArcSegment Point="{Binding SecondPoint}" Size="{Binding PieSize}" IsLargeArc="{Binding IsLargeArc}" SweepDirection="Clockwise"/>
                                        <LineSegment Point="{Binding Center}"/>
                                    </PathFigure.Segments>
                                </PathFigure>
                            </PathGeometry>
                        </GeometryGroup>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
                <TextBlock TextAlignment="{Binding TextAlign}" Width="50" Text="{Binding Percentage}" FontSize="14" Canvas.Top="{Binding Top}" Canvas.Left="{Binding Left}" Background="{Binding Color}"/>
            </Canvas>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Which actually displays a pie chart as expected however is very slow to start and throws a bunch of errors to the debugging output of the form:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=FirstPoint1; DataItem='PieChartDataPoint' (HashCode=60223391); target element is 'PathFigure' (HashCode=35353884); target property is 'StartPoint' (type 'Point')
```

It does this for FirstPoint1, SecondPoint1, Center, FirstPoint, SecondPoint, PieSize, and IsLargeArc

Basically any of the bindings inside of the Path.Data. I have not been able to find any help online but have tried to set the Relative source of the bindings to the ItemsControl by adding this line to the Bindings

```
RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}
```

Which stops the above error from showing but instead spits out these:

```
'System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=FirstPoint1; DataItem=null; target element is 'PathFigure' (HashCode=38648509); target property is 'StartPoint' (type 'Point')
```

And it stops displaying the control properly.